# Bad access crash app in-app ios

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, in-app

I have a problem with in-app. I have 2 in-apps in my app. But when I bought first and than i wanna buy second my app crash and it show me error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x10)`. On line with `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];` Can you help me?

Comment: Show more code. EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a common crash on iOS and gives only very few clues for debugging.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you've lost your reference to the object that used to be held in `payment`. You're going to need to provide more context, though.

Comment: also enable zombie mode for debugging.It looks like the object is released but still

Comment: Sorry guys for little information. I uploaded code http://pastebin.com/kTL8ZRqS

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in the post, not by linking to it. You can [edit] your post by using the link below the question's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're providing too little information. Still...

Are you setting `payment`?

```
SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
```

Does `product` exists and is type `SKProduct`?

Also you can't create a SKProduct. SKProducts come as a request response. Check your delegate method `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:`.

You should debug the whole process by setting breakpoints. Then you will be able to provide more information in case you don't resolve the issue by yourself.

Comment: I am sorry for little information I upload full code of in-app and product is type SKProduct and it exists. http://pastebin.com/kTL8ZRqS

Comment: I'm looking at your code. This won't resolve your issue but you should set the in-app purchase observer in a more general class, one that can be accessible all the time (your application delegate class, for example); otherwise, if for some reason the app crashes during download, the product won't be delivered. Besides you don't have to set the observer multiple times. Apart from this, did you notice that buyPackage always buy the same product ([validProducts objectAtIndex:0])? If you did so for testing purposes, does validProducts is different from nil?

Comment: Problem was that I dont free memory `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];`